# Unable to set responseType in post request angular 5, trying to capture file response from post api

Tags: angular, http, post, http-post, angular5

I am trying to set responseType to arraybuffer but it is giving error. The api is returning a file and I need to capture that and generate the file.

I am calling exportCartDetails as below that is triggered on onAdd event emitter on Mat Dialog.

```
const data1 = this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe(result => {
      this.exportCartDetails(result)
        .subscribe(
          mydata=>{
            console.log('data is all here');
            var file =new Blob([mydata],{type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
            var fileURL=URL.createObjectURL(file);
            let a =document.createElement("a");
            a.style.display = "none";
            a.href=fileURL;
            a.target="_blank";
            a.download="CartData.xls";
            a.click();
            a.remove();
         }
      )
        ,
    err=>{
    alert("Error in calling api");
    console.log(err);
  };
```

Export cart detail is below

```
  exportCartDetails(report_data: ReferenceDataApi): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    const headers=new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', '*' );    
    //header.set( 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + req.body.filename,);
    const response = new HttpResponse();
    console.log(this.report_data);
    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(url,this.report_data,{headers,responseType:'arraybuffer'})
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<ArrayBuffer>('exportCartDetails'))
    );    
}
```

Error is below.

```
ERROR in src/app/cart-detail/cart-detail.component.ts(118,91): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: ArrayBuffer; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
src/app/cart-detail/cart-detail.component.ts(118,113): error TS2352: Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

Comment: Does it work if your remove return type `ArrayBuffer` from `this.http.post(url,this.report_data,{headers,responseType:'arraybuffer'})` ??

Comment: or by adding `observe:body` parameter explicitly like `this.http.post(url,this.report_data,{headers, observe:'body', responseType:'arraybuffer'})`

Comment: @AmitChigadani yes the error is gone but now unable to download file

Comment: thank you so much for your comment. thank you so much. After following for you 1st comment, I did some changes and it worked. I was stuck at it for 2 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you could remove the expected return type `<ArrayBuffer>` from `httpClient.post()`.

```
return this.http.post(url,this.report_data,{headers,responseType:'arraybuffer'})
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<ArrayBuffer>('exportCartDetails'))
    );
```

Alternatively you could also try specifying alias to `'arraybuffer'` like

`responseType:'arraybuffer' as 'arraybuffer'`

There is an open issue regarding [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586)

Code :

```
return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(url,this.report_data,{headers,responseType:'arraybuffer' as 'arraybuffer'})
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError<ArrayBuffer>('exportCartDetails'))
   );
```